# Linking a domain name to a web server without full masking

Tags: domain-name-system, domain-name, namespaces

I'm currently trying to deploy my first website and I ran trough a small issue with DNS. I have my website www folder available (hosted on atlantic.net cloud) and I registered a domain through godaddy. However it only gives me 2 options there:
- to simply redirect the domain to the web server's IP (you can see the server's IP in the browser address while browsing the page)
- to redirect the domain to the server's IP but masking the entire address (the webpage address is always showing as mydomain.com regardless of the user's browsing). Browsing different pages never changes the browser address.

What do I need to do to access my website content without masking the entire address? (i.e the user should be able to see www.mydomain.com/pages while browsing different pages.

Comment: Have you tried to put atlantic.net dns server addresses in godaddy and then configure the dns at atlantic.net?

Comment: I forgot to mention, I did add the 3 atalantic nameservers (ns1,2,3.quickroutedns.com) to godaddy and in atlantic's page I have the domain I set this up: http://imgur.com/OQUQuZs but I get a blank page everytime I try to open the main page.

Comment: Does `nslookup www.yourdomain.com` shows your webserver ip address?

Comment: It did not. I updated that entry in godaddy's zone file, it now lists my webserver ip. nslookup still shows the wrong ip but I guess this could take a while to update. Should I have godaddy's redirect on in the domain settings or does the DNS take care of linking them?

Comment: You have to put the webserver ip in atlantic.net zone files not in godaddy. Make sure that a dns-check for yourdomain.com shows the correct dns servers from atlantic.net. Then rest you configure at atlantic.net.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the default nameservers at godaddy and point them to the atlantic.net nameservers. Then you add the domain at atlantic.net and configure the zones there. It can take some time to propagate the dns update.

Troubleshooting tips

- Either with nslookup or some online dns check utilites like http://www.dnsstuff.com/, see if your dns servers are updated and pointing to the right dns servers (in your case the atlantic.net servers not godaddy's).
- You can check with `nslookup www.yourdomain.com`if it resolves to the correct ip address of your webserver.

Comment: thank you. I was updating the zone file in godaddy, not atlantic. Everything is working as expected now. :)